# Is it possible to integrate DocuSign signature into a native iOS or Android app without any backend?

Tags: docusignapi

I am developing a couple of native mobile apps (Swift/iOS and Kotlin/Android) without any backend for now, and I would like to make it possible for users to sign a document from the app without any backend. Is that possible with DocuSign's API and SDKs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! For iOS, check out the [iOS SDK.](https://developers.docusign.com/ios_sdk/) It includes the ability to sign when the phone is offline, with automatic synchronization when the phone comes back online.

As an alternative, you can use the [Objective-C wrapper SDK.](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-objc-client)

For Android, we have the [Java SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client).

For either iOS or Android, you can also call the API directly from your mobile app.

Please submit additional questions if you run into any difficulties. Thanks for using DocuSign!

Answer (score 0):

For Android, the new mobile SDK is launched and you can read about it here https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk

The Java SDK mentioned below is now deprecated and will no longer be supported.